# UICollectionView with growing header view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I currently have a `UICollectionView` with a header of a fixed size.

If you pull down then the header moves down leaving a gap above it between the header and the nav bar. The header has a button at the top, a couple of labels at the bottom and the BG is an image.

If you push up then the header scrolls upwards to display more of the UICollectionView items.

This is all working fine. However, we require a change to the behaviour.

**What we want...**
What we want is for the header to start off the same as it is now.

[image]

**Pull down**
But if you pull down the top of the "header" should stick to the nav bar and the header should grow.

I can do this easily by making the collection view frame smaller, faking a header and accessing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods in the controller.

**Push Up**
If you push up then the header should do exactly what it's doing now. i.e. stay the same size and disappear underneath the nav bar.

This last bit is tricky. If I go my proposed change for the pull down then it will make this much harder.

**Question**
How can I include both of these functions?

I'm thinking of maybe having a header but making it completely blank?

Another idea I just had... Make the collection view full screen but set the section inset so has enough space for the fake header. Then I can intercept the scroll view delegate methods like above?

I think this sounds best unless anyone has a better idea?

Comment: if this question was  answered or you able to make what you wanted, please answer here for other know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make the header the desired (maximum) size but keep it hidden under the nav bar by calling `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` in `viewWillAppear:` of your `UICollectionViewController`?

As the `UIScrollViewDelegate` the controller could also take care of positioning the upper right button at the desired position while scrolling.